# Google chrome only runs in debug mode

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, debug

Today I updated my Ubuntu distribution to the latest available, from 20.04 to 22.04. During this update, everything went great, but at the time that I opened chrome browser, I noticed that this is a stuck loading screen.
But, if I launch chrome with the flags `--enable-logging --v=1` this will launch without a problem. I already tried to purge the application and reinstall it, but nothing worked. 
Any solution there? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You said you tried to purge did you remove it or not. What did you mean by nothing worked. DETAILS needed.

Comment: Hi @David, yes, I completely removed chrome from my system. "Nothing worked" means everything I tried didn't work. The only way to launch chrome that I found was with the flags previously mentioned. Please, let me know what else you need.